# how I can use setTimeout here in asyncStorage call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I am trying to get data from local memory using asyncStorage but there is one issue

```
 useEffect( async () => {
        try {

            if(activemanagegroup !== null) {
            var groupValue = JSON.stringify(activemanagegroup)
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('managementGroup', groupValue)
            
            }
            
            var listValue = JSON.stringify(list)    
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('selectedList', listValue)
        } catch (e) {
            console.log('Failed to save data')
        }
    },[activemanagegroup, list])


useEffect(() => {

        
          async function getData() {
            try {
                
                const managementGroupValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('managementGroup')
                const managedUsersList  = await AsyncStorage.getItem('selectedList')
                const activeManagementGroupSelected =  managementGroupValue != null ?  JSON.parse(managementGroupValue) : null
                const activeList = managedUsersList != null ?  JSON.parse(managedUsersList) : null
                setActiveManagementGroup(activeManagementGroupSelected)
                setNewList(activeList)
                
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error getting data', error)
            }
        }

    
        getData()
        
    
    },[activemanagegroup])
```

the problem is `selectedList` updates a second later after  `managementGroup` and due to that I end up getting old `selectedList`. How I can delay the call and make sure I get updated `selectedList` ?

Note: I am storing both these values once user presses a button.

Comment: Where in your code are you setting the values in the AsyncStorage?

Comment: Hey, just added that above

Comment: I don't think your suggestion will help, as I said userList is updating a little late so even with what you are suggesting I will always end up getting old list

Comment: Head up -> `useEffect( async () => {` useEffect expects a cleanup function as a return, not a promise.  As such when the component gets unmounted, your going to get some errors.

Comment: @Keith Can I do something like what I am doing while reading data ?

Comment: Yes, your second `useEffect` is ok, as your not returning a promise.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, I am really new with async await and still learning

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using AsyncStorage to retrieve the data more than once; once you have the data loaded initially, you should use React's built-in state management solutions to store the data instead of re-reading it from AsyncStorage.

Thus, I'd move your `getItem` calls to a separate `useEffect` that only runs once and updates the local React state:

```
const [managementGroupValue, setManagementGroupValue] = useState(null)
const [managedUsersList, setManagedUsersList] = useState(null) 

useEffect(() => {
          async function getData() {
            try {
                setManagementGroupValue(await AsyncStorage.getItem('managementGroup'))
                setManagedUsersList(await AsyncStorage.getItem('selectedList'))                
            } catch (error) {
                console.log('error getting data', error)
            }
        }
    
        getData()
    }, [])
```

and then use the `managementGroupValue` and `managedUsersList` variables to refer to that data instead of retrieving it from AsyncStorage each time.